# MuleESB Reporting

Tags: reporting, mule

Has anyone used any open source, or relatively low-cost, reporting that works with MuleESB. The Mule Management console looks really good, but the cost of it look prohibitively high for the personal project I want to use it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by reporting? If you mean monitoring, then use the [Mule JMX Agent](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/JMX+Management): you'll get plenty of data points to get the pulse of your running instances.